# JSF lifecycle phase order

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I've made small jsf app and a bit confused about lifecycle order, i'm getting unexpected NPE on postback even though i'm creating that object on every request. Can someone explain what's happening under the covers. Here is the code:

Entity.java

```
public class Entity {

    private Long id;
    private String property;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void setProperty(String property) {
        this.property = property;
    }
}
```

Bean.java

```
import javax.enterprise.inject.Model;

@Model
public class Bean {

    private Long id;
    private Entity entity;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Entity getEntity() {
        return entity;
    }

    public void loadEntity() {
        this.entity = new Entity();
    }
}
```

edit.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">
    <f:view transient="true">
        <f:metadata>
            <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.id}"/>
            <f:viewAction onPostback="true" action="#{bean.loadEntity()}"/>
        </f:metadata>
        <h:body>
            <o:form useRequestURI="true">
                <h:inputText value="#{bean.entity.property}"/>
                <h:commandButton value="Save"/>
            </o:form>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

Comment: for information, i'm towards complete stateless architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Action methods like `<f:viewAction action>` are invoked during invoke application phase. The model values are updated during update model values phase. So, the entity is created one phase too late and still `null` when property needs to be set.

Get rid of the `<f:viewAction>` and make it a `@PostConstruct` method instead.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.entity = new Entity();
}
```

Comment: this is just a dummy statement, in fact i have to load it from somewhere and i need id to be present.

Comment: Then grab it via [`@Param`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/Param) instead of `<f:viewParam>`.

Comment: then i won't be able to use it via includeViewParams